# Convergence issues on hierarchical probit model with NUTS and Metropolis

Tags: python, hierarchical-data, bayesian, pymc3

I am trying to extend the hierarchical model from Gelman and Hill [reproduced in PyMC3 here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fonnesbeck/multilevel_modeling/blob/master/multilevel_modeling.ipynb?create=1) to binary outcome data by adding a probit transformation and making the outcome follow a Bernoulli distribution. Right now I'm using toy data, so I know the true values. Alpha should be .1, beta should be .5.

The model runs fine with a NUTS sampler before the extension. Once I add it, the estimates slowly increase and keep increasing until the model stalls anywhere between 10 and 200 iterations. Here's an image from when it made it all the way to 120 (a relatively long run). 
[image: traceplots from NUTS sample]

Before the extension, Metropolis needs a good 200,000 iterations to get a good fix on the true parameter values, but it does eventually. After the extension it stalls somewhere between 30k and 50k. Unlike with NUTS, it completely crashes when you try to stop it post-stall, so I don't have a picture. Stopping it earlier gives an estimate over beta roughly over zero, but with a wide spread.

The code is pasted below.

I'm not sure if it's a sampling problem, or a specification problem. Is there a better way to specify a Probit? Any tips on other samplers to try? I've stripped my model down as far as I can for the test, and narrowed it down to breaking once I add probit extension, but I'm at a loss for what to do next.

```
#Generate Data
n=100
#Determine how many observations per group
evts=np.random.randint(10,100,n)
#Determine which groups will be receive treatment
x_g=np.random.binomial(1,.3,n)
#pre-create distribution of betas for groups 
mu = np.random.normal(.5,.2,n)
#preallocate space in a dataframe
i = np.zeros(evts.sum())
y_obs = pd.DataFrame({'y':i.copy(),
                      'x':i.copy(),
                      'grp':i.copy()},
                     index = range(evts.sum()))
#populate dataframe with simulated data
i=0
for grp in range(100):
    #index of observations for a given group
    ind = list(range(i,(i+evts[grp])))
    i += evts[grp]
    #generate outcomes using
    #different dgp depending on treatment
    if x_g[grp] ==1:
        #shortcut to make sure 1>p>0
        p_i = max((.1 + mu[grp]),0.01)
        p_i = min(p_i,1)
        out = np.random.binomial(1,p_i,evts[grp])
    else:
        out = np.random.binomial(1,.1,evts[grp])
    #Assign to dataframe
    y_obs.loc[ind,'y'] = out
    y_obs.loc[ind,'x'] = x_g[grp]
    y_obs.loc[ind,'grp'] = grp
y_obs = y_obs.astype(int)
print('starting model')
with pm.Model() as test_model:
    #hyperpriors
    mu_a=pm.Normal('mu_a',mu=0, sd=100**2)
    sig_a = pm.Uniform('sig_a',lower=0,upper=100)
    mu_b=pm.Normal('mu_b',mu=0, sd=100**2)
    sig_b = pm.Uniform('sig_b',lower=0,upper=100)
    #priors
    a = pm.Normal('a',mu=mu_a,sd = sig_a, shape=n)
    b = pm.Normal('b',mu=mu_b,sd = sig_b, shape=n)

    eps = pm.Uniform('eps',lower=0,upper=100)

    est = a[y_obs.grp] + b[y_obs.grp] * y_obs.x
    #I get correct estimates when I 
    #stop here using commented out line. 
#     y_hat = pm.Normal('y_hat',
#                       mu=est,
#                       sd=eps, 
#                       observed = y_obs.y)

    #Probit transformation:
    y_hat = pm.Normal('y_hat',
                      mu=est,
                      sd=eps, 
                      shape=y_obs.shape[0])

    mu_y = tt.mean(y_hat)
    eps_hat = tt.var(y_hat)
    p_hat = 0.5 * (1 + tt.erf((y_hat-mu_y) / (eps_hat*tt.sqrt(2))))

    y = pm.Bernoulli('y',p=p_hat, observed = y_obs.y)


with test_model:
    #Either:
    mu,sds,elbo = pm.variational.advi(n=100000)
    step = pm.NUTS(scaling=test_model.dict_to_array(sds),
                   is_cov=True)
    test_trace = pm.sample(200, step, start=mu)
    #or
#     step=pm.Metropolis()
#     test_trace = pm.sample(50000)

pm.traceplot(test_trace)#[-5000::3])
```

NOTE: edited to fix typo in line:         'step = pm.NUTS(scaling=test_model.dict_to_array(sds),`

EDIT: I made better simulation data for the probit extension for the model originally posted. (the original data generation was Now ADVI gives better estimates, so it's starting in around the right place, but NUTS still stalls very quickly (at around ten iterations). Metropolis straight up fails: I did a first round of 5000 iterations, and got an error when trying to plot the trace.

New data generation:

```
n=100
evts=np.random.randint(10,100,n)
x_g=np.random.binomial(1,.3,n)
i = np.zeros(evts.sum())
mu = np.random.normal(.5,.2,n)
mu0 = np.random.normal(.1,.05,n)
y_obs = pd.DataFrame({'y':i.copy(),'x':i.copy(),'grp':i.copy()},index = range(evts.sum()))
i=0
for grp in range(100):
    ind = list(range(i,(i+evts[grp])))
    i += evts[grp]
    if x_g[grp] ==1:
        est = mu0[grp] + mu[grp]
    else:
        est=mu0[grp]
    p_hat = tt.nnet.sigmoid(est).eval()
    y_obs.loc[ind,'y_hat'] = est
    y_obs.loc[ind,'y'] = np.random.binomial(1,p_hat,len(ind))
    y_obs.loc[ind,'x'] = x_g[grp]
    y_obs.loc[ind,'grp'] = grp
y_obs['grp']=y_obs.grp.astype(np.int64)
```

Error for metropolis when pymc3 tries to plot a density:

> ValueError: v cannot be empty

Comment: `scaling` in NUTS should be the variance, not the std. Use `test_model.dict_to_array(sds) ** 2`

Comment: Are you sure? I took the syntax from sample code in response to the github issue on initializing from advi. 
https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/c7eabf17ddbc25b950720bc86f1966478a487c79/pymc3/examples/stochastic_volatility.ipynb 
From here: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1087
And here: 
https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/pull/1088

Comment: They also use the returned stds in the documentation: https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/NUTS_scaling_using_ADVI.html#

Comment: I'm sure. See eg https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1448. This should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks, good catch. I'll change the scaling and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand what you are trying to do, but shouldn't this model work:

```
with pm.Model() as test_model:
    #hyperpriors
    mu_a = pm.Flat('mu_a')
    sig_a = pm.HalfCauchy('sig_a', beta=2.5)

    mu_b = pm.Flat('mu_b')
    sig_b = pm.HalfCauchy('sig_b', beta=2.5)

    #priors
    a_raw = pm.Normal('a_raw', mu=0, sd=1, shape=n)
    a = pm.Deterministic('a', mu_a + sig_a * a_raw)

    b_raw = pm.Normal('b_raw', mu=0, sd=1, shape=n)
    b = pm.Deterministic('b', mu_b + sig_b * b_raw)

    est = a[y_obs.grp.values] + b[y_obs.grp.values] * y_obs.x

    y = pm.Bernoulli('y', p=tt.nnet.sigmoid(est), observed = y_obs.y)
```

This is a logit, not a probit model. If you want a probit for some reason, you an replace `tt.nnet.sigmoid` by a standard probit function.

This still has a somewhat hard time with your dataset, but I think that is because of a mistake in the data generation: you assume a constant a for all groups of 0.1, but in the model you allow the a values to differ by group. The sampler has trouble with very small values for sig_a (the true value is 0 after all...).

**Edit**: Some more explanations: The change to use standard normal `a_raw` and `b_raw` and then transform them to a `Normal(mu=mu_a, sd=sig_a)` using `pm.Deterministic` does not change the posterior, but it makes it easier for the sampler. It is called a non-centered parametrization. For a more in depth description of the topic see eg http://mc-stan.org/documentation/case-studies/divergences_and_bias.html, this should also help you to understand, why very small variances can be problematic.

**Edit**: New data generation

```
n = 100
evts=np.random.randint(10,100,n)
x_g=np.random.binomial(1,.3,n)
i = np.zeros(evts.sum())
mu = np.random.normal(.5,.2,n)
mu0 = np.random.normal(.1,.05,n)
y_obs = pd.DataFrame({'y':i.copy(),'x':i.copy(),'grp':i.copy()},
                     index = range(evts.sum()))
i = 0
for grp in range(100):
    ind = list(range(i,(i+evts[grp])))
    i += evts[grp]
    if x_g[grp] ==1:
        est = mu0[grp] + mu[grp]
    else:
        est=mu0[grp]
    p_hat = tt.nnet.sigmoid(est).eval()
    y_obs.loc[ind,'y_hat'] = est
    y_obs.loc[ind,'y'] = np.random.binomial(1,p_hat,len(ind))
    y_obs.loc[ind,'x'] = x_g[grp]
    y_obs.loc[ind,'grp'] = grp
y_obs['grp']=y_obs.grp.astype(np.int64)
```

Sampling using

```
with test_model:
    trace = pm.sample(2000, tune=1000, njobs=4)
```

This is finished after about three minutes

```
Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
Initializing NUTS using advi...
  8%|▊         | 15977/200000 [00:15<02:51, 1070.66it/s]Median ELBO converged.
Finished [100%]: Average ELBO = -4,458.8

100%|██████████| 2000/2000 [02:48<00:00,  9.99it/s]
```

No divergent transitions:

```
test_trace[1000:].diverging.sum()
```

All using pymc3 and theano master. (Both are about to ready for a new release)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "The sampler has a to try even very small values for sig_a (the true value is 0 after all...)" 
I'm also not sure why having a very small (0) variance for a would make it fail. Especially since it correctly estimates a as .1 when I don't do the probit transformation at the end. So I think there's an error in the last few lines rather than the hyperpriors.

Comment: I'll give your model a try tonight, but it looks pretty similar, so I'm not sure why it should work better than what I've got, (which I would like to understand, since it's a toy version of an extended model I'm applying to real data). And there are some steps there that I'm not sure why you took. For example, why assign b twice rather than allow it to be a draw from a normal distribution, or even drawing a random error. But what's more intuitive probably depends on which of the many valid ways you think about hierarchical models.

Comment: Haven't been able to get this model to run at all. ADVI initialization returns mu=NaN. Without initialization NUTS stalls pretty much immediately. Metropolis runs, but so far gives pretty wild estimates.

Comment: Edited the question with more appropriate data. ADVI gets close, but NUTS stalls and Metropolis fails. So that gives me a little more confidence in the specification.

Comment: That this does not work for you is strange, it does sample nicely for me. I'm on master at the moment, so maybe that's the reason. I did not understand what you were doing with `y_hat` in the original post. Is that to model overdispersion?

Comment: I think you hit the crux of the problem. I hadn't thought y_hat through. est is already a transformed normal, I didn't need to wrap it in a second normal distribution. I pulled that out, and NUTS worked, albeit very slowly. (2-3 min per iteration by the time I stopped it.) Your explanation about the posteriors and making it easier to sample was super helpful. I'll play around with that a bit tonight and see if I can get it to sample more quickly.

Comment: I also followed the advice on issues 1147 and 1156, and advi works seems to work now for things that were crashing before. I'll try it on the model you posted as soon as I have the resources free. https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1147 
Thanks for all your help

Comment: I can get it to run now, but not to recover the true values. And this is after adding some variance alpha. Which is strange, because it should be the same model.

Comment: Still can't get it to replicate. What sampler did you use, and how did you initialize it?

Comment: Got it to work. I think I found the problem, and it had more to do with the data being used than the model specification.