# MCMC convergence in hierarchical model with (large) time^2 term in pymc3

Tags: python, bayesian, survival-analysis, mcmc, pymc3

I have a hierarchical logit that has observations over time. Following [Carter 2010](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjypKnpj_fSAhWV8oMKHeEqBUIQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sas.rochester.edu%2Fpsc%2Fsignorino%2Fresearch%2FCarter_Signorino_2010_PA.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE2bYK8Pq2RiTQm7nD6coGRynNBeg&sig2=Gnnk33O27iUYB2TRth5ihg), I have included a time, time^2, and time^3 term. The model mixes using Metropolis or NUTS before I add the time variables. HamiltonianMC fails. NUTS and Metropolis also work with time. But NUTS and Metropolis fail with time^2 and time^3, but they fail differently and in a puzzling way. However, unlike in other models that fail for more obvious model specification reasons, ADVI still gives an estimate, (and ELBO is not inf).

- NUTS either stalls early (last time it made it to 60 iterations), or progresses too quickly and returns an empty traceplot with an error about varnames.
- Metropolis errors out immediately with a dimension mismatch error. It looks like the one in [this github error](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/842), but I'm using a Bernoulli outcome, not a negative binomial. The end of the error looks like: `ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[0] = 1, input[4].shape[0] = 18)`
- I get an empty trace when I try HamiltonianMC. It returns the starting values with no mixing
- ADVI gives me a mean and a standard deviation.
- I increased the ADVI iterations by a lot. It gave pretty close to the same starting points and NUTS still failed.
- I double checked that the fix for the github issue is in place in the version of pymc3 I'm running. It is.

My intuition is that this has something to do with how huge the time^2 and time^3 variables get, since I'm looking over a large time-frame. Time^3 starts at 0 and goes to 64,000.

Here is what I've tried for sampling so far. Note that I have small sample sizes while testing, since it takes so long to run (if it finishes) and I'm just trying to get it to sample at all. Once I find one that works, I'll up the number of iterations

```
with my_model:
    mu,sds,elbo = pm.variational.advi(n=500000,learning_rate=1e-1)
    print(mu['mu_b'])
    step = pm.NUTS(scaling=my_model.dict_to_array(sds)**2,
                   is_cov=True)
    my_trace = pm.sample(500, 
                         step=step, 
                         start=mu,
                         tune=100)
```

I've also done the above with tune=1000

I've also tried a Metropolis and Hamiltonian.

```
with my_model:
    my_trace = pm.sample(5000,step=pm.Metropolis())

with my_model:
    my_trace = pm.sample(5000,step=pm.HamiltonianMC())
```

Questions:

- Is my intuition about the size and spread of the time variables reasonable?
- Are there ways to sample square and cubed terms more effectively? I've searched, but can you perhaps point me to a resource on this so I can learn more about it?
- What's up with Metropolis and the dimension mismatch error?
- What's up with the empty trace plots for NUTS? Usually when it stalls, the trace up until the stall works.
- Are there alternative ways to handle time that might be easier to sample?

I haven't posted a toy model, because it's hard to replicate without the data. I'll add a toy model once I replicate with simulated data. But the actual model is below:

```
with pm.Model() as my_model:
    mu_b = pm.Flat('mu_b')
    sig_b = pm.HalfCauchy('sig_b',beta=2.5)
    b_raw = pm.Normal('b_raw',mu=0,sd=1,shape=n_groups)
    b = pm.Deterministic('b',mu_b + sig_b*b_raw)

    t1 = pm.Normal('t1',mu=0,sd=100**2,shape=1)
    t2 = pm.Normal('t2',mu=0,sd=100**2,shape=1)
    t3 = pm.Normal('t3',mu=0,sd=100**2,shape=1)

    est =(b[data.group.values]* data.x.values) +\
        (t1*data.t.values)+\
        (t2*data.t2.values)+\
        (t3*data.t3.values)

    y = pm.Bernoulli('y', p=tt.nnet.sigmoid(est), observed = data.y)
```

BREAKTHROUGH 1: Metropolis error

Weird syntax issue. Theano seemed to be confused about a model with both constant and random effects. I created a constant in data equal to 0, `data['c']=0` and used it as an index for the time, time^2 and time^3 effects, as follows:

```
est =(b[data.group.values]* data.x.values) +\
            (t1[data.c.values]*data.t.values)+\
            (t2[data.c.values]*data.t2.values)+\
            (t3[data.c.values]*data.t3.values)
```

I don't think this is the whole issue, but it's a step in the right direction. I bet this is why my asymmetric specification didn't work, and if so, suspect it may sample better.

UPDATE: It sampled! Will now try some of the suggestions for making it easier on the sampler, including using the specification [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42785737/7335256). But at least it's working!

Comment: Which version of pymc3 and theano are you using?

Comment: pymc3 3.0, Theano 0.9.0.

Checked the source on the logpow function, and realized that it doesn't look like the corrected one in issue #842, so I'm going to overwrite the function as soon as it finishes a run. It's almost done running NUTS with a much much longer number of ADVI iterations, in case that helped it initialize better--but I don't expect it to have, since it returned the same mu for the parameters I printed between ADVI and NUTS. But it's almost done. 
Thanks again, btw!

Comment: @aseyboldt I'm also using the asymmetric specification you suggested on most but not all variables. When I tried to add group level covariates using the specification you suggested the other day for my previous question, I got the dimension mismatch error for Metropolis, a positive definite error for HamiltonianMC, and a similar problem with NUTS where I get empty traces. 
The relevant part of the model was: (see next comment, out of characters)

Comment: @aseyboldt
`    mu_a = pm.Flat('mu_a')
    sig_a = pm.HalfCauchy('sig_a', beta=2.5)
    mu_a_est = mu_a + (b1 * b_vars.var1)
    a_raw = pm.Normal('a_raw',mu=0,sd=1,shape=n_grps)
    a=pm.Deterministic('a',mu_a_est + sig_a*a_raw)`

changed to: 

`    mu_a = pm.Normal('mu_a',mu=0,sd=100**2)
    sig_a = pm.HalfCauchy('sig_a', beta=2.5)
    mu_a_est = mu_a + (b1 * b_vars.var1)
    a=pm.Normal('a', mu=mu_a_est, sd = sig_a)`

If it runs after I change the logpow function, I'll try it again and post here.

Comment: @asaybolt. Increasing the ADVI iterations didn't help. It returned empty traceplots, and trying to traceplot returned a type error.
I also checked again, and I have the correct logpow function. There were two accepted commits tied to the issue and I'd only looked at the first one, but the source on mine matches the final version of logpow in master.

Comment: Ew, the code did not look good. I'll try again.  Still can't do line breaks, but hopefully this helps.
___
`mu_a = pm.Flat('mu_a')` 
___
`sig_a = pm.HalfCauchy('sig_a', beta=2.5)`  
___
`mu_a_est = mu_a + (b1 * b_vars.var1) `  
___
`a_raw = pm.Normal('a_raw',mu=0,sd=1,shape=n_grps)`  
___
`a=pm.Deterministic('a',mu_a_est + sig_a*a_raw)`   
___
changed to:   
___
` mu_a = pm.Normal('mu_a',mu=0,sd=100**2) `  
___
`sig_a = pm.HalfCauchy('sig_a', beta=2.5)`   
___
`mu_a_est = mu_a + (b1 * b_vars.var1)`  
___
`a=pm.Normal('a', mu=mu_a_est, sd = sig_a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the dataset to play with it is hard to give a definite answer, but here is my best guess:

To me, it is a bit unexpected to hear about the third order polynomial in there. I haven't read the paper, so I can't really comment on it, but I think this might be the reason for your problems. Even very small values for `t3` will have a huge influence on the predictor. To keep this reasonable, I'd try to change the parametrization a bit: First make sure that your predictor is centered (something like `data['t'] = data['t'] - data['t'].mean()` and after that define `data.t2` and `data.t3`). Then try to set a more reasonable prior on `t2` and `t3`. They should be pretty small, so maybe try something like

```
t1 = pm.Normal('t1',mu=0,sd=1,shape=1)
t2 = pm.Normal('t2',mu=0,sd=1,shape=1)
t2 = t2 / 100
t3 = pm.Normal('t3',mu=0,sd=1,shape=1)
t3 = t3 / 1000
```

If you want to look at other models, you could try to model your predictor as a `GaussianRandomWalk` or a Gaussian Process.

Updating pymc3 to the latest release candidate should also help, the sampler was improved quit a bit.

**Update** I just noticed you don't have an intercept term in your model. Unless there is a good reason for that you probably want to add

```
intercept = pm.Flat('intercept')
est = (intercept
       + b[..] * data.x
       + ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Will play around with it and report back.
On the intercept, I have random intercepts for a couple different group categorizations, I just wanted to find a balance between posting way too much code, and posting what was just necessary. I was having trouble figuring out a survival model specification with multiple crosscutting random effects, and time varying covariates. Even though that's the ideal model. I'd read about using a random walk (and problems with it) but hadn't quite figured out the specification. Do you have a reference you recommend?

Comment: The paper references an earlier paper that says splines can be used to make a logit essentially equivalent to a survival model. It then reviews the literature since that first model was published and points out that no one uses them right, so suggests t,t^2, and t^3, which are a good approximation and outperform alternatives. So since I was having trouble with the survival specification, this seemed like a legit alternative. But if I can't sample a huge t3, then maybe it's not as viable as I hoped it would be.

Comment: The fact that the timespan is large, doesn't change anything. You can just standardize your predictor to get around numerical problems. I'm just not sure if it is a good model, but of course this depends on the dataset. If your timespan is large, then your predictor could get larger and smaller a couple of times. And third order polynomials might do strange things on the left and right end.

Comment: There are a couple of examples about GP in the pymc3 doc (look at the example notebooks). In case the Bernoulli is to code censoring (a wild guess from my part) you could also have a look at https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/master/pymc3/examples/censored_data.py